# Update Interval Laggy Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am making a game. I am using

```
this.interval = setInterval(updateGame, 0.5);
```

to redraw the canvas and characters. I wanted to add something that makes the characters blink when damaged. To do this, I added a variable called frame and had it increment 1 everything the update function was called. Then I said to only draw the character if frame was divisible by 20.

This solutions works, but it looks weirdly awful. It seems like the intervals aren't equally spaced and its looks kinda laggy, like the character is blinking for unequal amounts of time. Does anyone know how to fix this? Set interval should be based on time not frame rate so I am not sure why this is happening.

Thank You!

Comment: use requestAnimationFrame https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: The second argument is the interval in milliseconds. Do you really expect it to run and update the DOM 2,000 times per second? 25 frames per second is once every 40 ms.

Comment: I will look into requestAnimationFrame. RobG, as for your comment, I tried using like 20 and the character ends up moving pretty slow, because i only move him one pixel every update. However, if I change it to have him move more it look choppy. I could only increase the speed by decreasing the update interval. Is there another way?

Comment: The display can only show 60fps, You move the character by how far it can move in the 1/60th of a second. Set the speed `const charSpeed = 20;` as 20 pixels per second. then every farme (called from requestAnimationFrame) move the character `character.x += charSpeed / 60;`